# CanActivate guards on child routes run before parent Resolve finish

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-route-guards, angular-resolver

I'm trying to resolve data before navigating to children routes as i have to use that data in children guard. The issue is parent resolver, resolves data after the child guard is fired. Resolver takes long time to resolve data

```
// app.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'warehouse', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'warehouse',
        loadChildren: './warehouse/warehouse.module#WarehouseModule'
        // loadChildren: () => WarehouseModule
      }
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
      Site: SiteResolver // should be resolved before the guard is invoked.
    }
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

// warehouse.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'cash', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'cash', component: CashComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] // should be invoked after the parent resolver resloves th data }

];
```

Here, the parent resolver i.e. SiteResolver resolves after the child guard i.e. RouteGuard is invoked. What i want is SiteResolver to resolve data first and then RouteGuard should fire, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: As you can see here: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard, the resolver is considered a guard itself but has a minor priority compared to the route guard. So the order is not interchangeable. First comes the route guard and then the resolver.

Comment: This happens for me when i refresh the browser having the child route. Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is the correct method. But after going through a lot of angular issues , i found a workaround.

Instead of resolve , use canActivate to fetch data and store the data in the service. Below is the code snippet for the same

```
@Injectable()
export class FetchUserData implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}
  public modalRef: BsModalRef;
  canActivate() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get("some/api/route")
      .map(e => {
        if (e) {
          this.userService.setUserDetails(e);
          return true;
        }
        return true;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
  }
}
```

It worked for me well. You will have no problem in refreshing the child route.

Comment: Seems to be working solution, but still I would request angular team to fix this issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24187

Comment: My solution was to use resolvers instead of guards. Then the syncronous order and hierarchy will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

Usage notes
When both guard and resolvers are specified, the resolvers are not executed until all guards have run and succeeded. For example, consider the following route configuration:

```html
{
 path: 'base'
 canActivate: [BaseGuard],
 resolve: {data: BaseDataResolver}
 children: [
  {
    path: 'child',
    guards: [ChildGuard],
    component: ChildComponent,
    resolve: {childData: ChildDataResolver}
   }
 ]
}
```

The order of execution is: **BaseGuard**, **ChildGuard**, **BaseDataResolver**, **ChildDataResolver**.

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this situation was to **wrap** the entire application in a **lazy module** and hang **canLoad** on it

```
{
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canLoad: [PortalResolver],
        loadChildren: () => import('./portal/portal.module').then(m => m.PortalModule),
      }
    ],
  },
```