# Angular 7 resolve data before CanActivate of child route

Tags: angular

```
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  resolve: {
    userData: UserDataResolver
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'manage-users',
      component: ManageUsersComponent,
      canActivate: [ManageUsersGuard],
    },
```

This is my route, the parent route is dashboard, all child routes have `snapshot.data.userData` because `UserDataResolver` gets the data for the user after passing `AuthGuard`.

`ManageUsersGuard` needs `userData` that is resolved by his parent route in order to know whether if you can access that route or not, I don't want to create another API call while I know that I already get that data.

**Problem**
`ManageUsersGuard` is being activated before the resolver of the parent route, why is that and what is the right approach?

Comment: Add `resolve: {userData: UserDataResolver}` to a parent route. You can use empty routes `{path: '', resolve: {userData: UserDataResolver}, children: [...]}`. You'll find the data in the *parent* of the activated route.

Comment: You can use `canActivateChild` in  `children: [
    {
      path: 'manage-users',
      component: ManageUsersComponent,
      canActivateChild: [ManageUsersGuard],
    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428112/canactivate-guards-on-child-routes-run-before-parent-resolve-finish